# Proper hook for domready with Ember.js

Tags: jquery, ember.js

What is the proper way to run JavaScript (in my case, jQuery) to modify a part of the DOM (an Ember view).

Using `didInsertElement` in my view doesn't run betwen route context changes. E.g. from one post to another post.

```
App.PageView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log(this.$().find('img').length);
    }
});
```

Tried using the `afterRender` hook but same result. I assume it is because Ember only updates the Handlebars variables and not the view it self, since they are from the same model.

```
App.PageView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
    },
    afterRenderEvent: function() {
        console.log(this.$().find('img').length);
    }
});
```

I believe I got it working attaching an observer to the didInsertElement like this:

```
App.PageView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
    }.observes('controller.images'),
    afterRenderEvent: function() {
        if (this.$()) {
            console.log(this.$().find('img').length);
        }
    }
});
```

The observes is listening to my 'images' property on my model which seems to work. Is the the right way to do it? Seems a bit exccessive or what do I miss?

As an example, my model templates have some images I need to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case a solid approach is to observe a/the property that changes, as you have noted, within the `View`. However, there is no need to trigger the `afterRender`, just act on the DOM as it is required.

Example,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xixit/1/edit

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  images:[
    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/10/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/12/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/15/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/17/"
         ],
  actions:{
    addImage:function(){
 this.get("images").pushObject("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/"+parseInt(Math.random()*10,10)+"/");
    }
  }
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  showImages:false,
  styleImages:function(){
    /*use this, or something simple like the function runCode at the end (examples, http://jsfiddle.net/melc/sy6Ax/)*/
    /*or also observe the length, if new images added*/
    Ember.run.next(function(){
      this.$('img').addClass("img-borders");
    });
  }.observes("showImages","controller.images.@each"),
  actions:{
    toggleImages:function(){
      this.toggleProperty("showImages");
    }
  }
});



function runCode(selector,theMethod,timeInMillis){
    if($(selector).length>0){
        theMethod();
    }else{
        setTimeout(function(){runCode(selector,theMethod,timeInMillis);},timeInMillis);
    }
}
```

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <button {{action toggleImages target="view"}}>images</button>
<br/><br/>
    {{#if view.showImages}}
    {{#each img in images}}
    <img {{bind-attr src=img}}/>
    {{/each}}
    <br/>
    <button class="btn-add-img" {{action addImage}}> add image</button>
    {{/if}}

  </script>
```

**css**

```
img{
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}

img.img-borders{
  border:1px solid grey;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 blue;
}

.btn-add-img{
  float:left;
  clear:both;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. To avoid getting undefined I had to add an extra check inside Ember.run.next() like so: if (!self.$()) { return false; }